# JavaScript code is not executed even if I autoLoad the page with scripts:true

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have two html pages:

**1. Complex.htm**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Complex Layout</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/ext-all.css" />

    <!-- GC -->

<style type="text/css">

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ext-all-debug.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Ext.require(['*']);

    Ext.onReady(function() {

        //Ext.QuickTips.init();
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    //title: 'Container Panel',
    split: true,
    //bodyStyle: 'padding:15px',
height : '100%',
width : '100%',
layout:'border',
defaults: {
    collapsible: true,
    split: true,
    bodyStyle: 'padding:15px'
},
items: [{
    title: 'Footer',
    region: 'south',
    cmargins: '5 0 0 0'
},{
    title: 'Navigation',
    region:'west',
    margins: '5 0 0 0',
    cmargins: '5 5 0 0',
    width: 175,
    minSize: 100,
    maxSize: 250
},
{
    xtype:'tabpanel',
    title: 'Main Content',
    collapsible: false,
    region:'center',
    //margins: '5 0 0 0',
    items : [
        {
            //xtype:'tabpanel',
            title: 'Tab1',
            collapsible: false,
            //region:'center',
            margins: '5 0 0 0',
            activeTab:0,
            //
            items: [{
                html : 'dsfds'
            }
            ]
            //
        },
        {
            //xtype:'tabpanel',
            title: 'Tab2',
            collapsible: false,
            //region:'center',
            margins: '5 0 0 0',
            activeTab:0,
            items:[{
            html :'Html'
            }]
        },
        { 
            title : 'Tab3',  
            loader: {
                autoLoad: true,
                url: 'http://localhost/MVC/ExtJs/demo/Form.htm',
                renderer: 'html',
                scripts : true,
            }
         }
    ]
}]
});
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**2. Form.htm**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Complex Layout</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/ext-all.css" />

    <!-- GC -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("sdfdsf");
</script>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ext-all-debug.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Ext.require(['*']);
    alert("alert");
    Ext.onReady(function() {

        //Ext.QuickTips.init();


        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    //title: 'Container Panel',
    split: true,
    //bodyStyle: 'padding:15px',
height : '100%',
width : '100%',
layout:'border',
defaults: {
    collapsible: true,
    split: true,
    bodyStyle: 'padding:15px'
},
items: [
{
    //xtype:'tabpanel',
    title: 'Main Content',
    collapsible: false,
    region:'center',
            items: [{
   xtype: 'textfield',
   fieldLabel: 'Director in form',
   name: 'director',
   anchor: '100%',
   vtype: 'name'
},{
   xtype: 'datefield',
   fieldLabel: 'Released',
   name: 'released',
   disabledDays: [1,2,3,4,5]
},{
   xtype: 'radio',
   fieldLabel: 'Filmed In',
   name: 'filmed_in',
   boxLabel: 'Color'
} // more fields go here //
]

}]
});


        /*global Ext:false */
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Form Content

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I am trying to load Form.htm inside a tab in Complex.htm. The content of form.htm i.e. "Form Content" is successfully loaded but the ExtJs components in Form.htm are not loaded. Even alert is not executed. I googled it a lot but could not find any thing useful.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Don't do it like that. Instead, send back json with your component information. Look at the component-loader example, specifically how it loads the last panel with components.

Comment: I have requirement that every form, report or container (for example given two pages) must be able to be displayed independently as well. If I use json then I wont be able to show form.htm if user request it directly from browser. :(

Comment: I'd suggest you change your architecture then. Doing it the way you've suggested won't be a good idea.

Comment: What is the problem with current architecture? I am generating ExtJs code using XSLT for each requested page. Each page should be able to be requested independently.

Answer (score 0):

If both pages have to be displayed independently, wrap your `Form.htm` in [IFrame](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ux.IFrame) to separate it from `Complex.htm`:

```
{
    xtype: "uxiframe",
    id: "idiframe",
    src: "http://localhost/MVC/ExtJs/demo/Form.htm"
}
```